# Why do my image links have this weirdly shaped outline?

Tags: html, css

I don't mind the border appearing, its just the strange bit at the top that I dislike. I know I can work around of this, getting rid of the border altogether by using `outline: 0`, but I also know [that's bad](http://www.outlinenone.com/).

The HTML setup is

```
<li>
<a href='..'><img alt='..' src='..'/></a>
<a href='..'>...</a>
</li>
```

An extract of the CSS:

```
li{
    display: block;
    width: 9em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    height: 12em;
    text-align: center;
}

li img{
    height: 8em;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(The effect is similar if the two are combined in a single `<a>`.)

I think this is related to using `display: block` on the image. I've reproduced the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/pvd69wce/

[image: Example of strange border]

Comment: can't you just use outline: 0 none; ?

Comment: I would, but accessibility seems to suggest I shouldn't (e.g. [outlinenone.com](http://www.outlinenone.com/)).

Comment: @8128 it suggests you shouldn't, but also that if you do to provide alternative styling.  You could still have an outline or other styling on the text (if it's not part of the image, which looks likely) and have no outline on the image.  The user will still have the feedback then

Comment: You are free to define a different style to highlight your elements such, that users know they can be clicked.

Comment: I think the question is about the weird shape??

Comment: I think you just have an extra newline above your image which makes that 'weird' shape.

Comment: post the styles and your html on jsfiddle.net, some styles are doing that.. it works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/dk9dqLd9/

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle.net http://jsfiddle.net/pvd69wce/

Comment: there is nothing wrong with removing outline from a link. You should how ever add an alternative way of highlighting the link on focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the outline, one solution is to give `display:inline-block` to the `<a>`.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  width: 9em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  height: 12em;
  text-align: center;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
li img {
  height: 8em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>
      <img alt='' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Merton_College_Oxford_Coat_Of_Arms.svg' />
    </a>
    <a href='##'>Merton</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To be honest though, I'm not entirely sure why this works exacty. Nor indeed, where the extra lines do come from when the `<a>` is not an inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative way you could think about assuming if the links are going to the same position is adding `outline:none` to the link but also adding a hover/focus effect on the image to highlight the link below it as to help for accessibility

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/ojXYgo